# Can't connect to proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

If I use a proxy, I can not connect to it. I tried speedy, slow, USA, and int'l servers, but none work. I am certain it is not a virus, I've scanned multiple times, and have not downloaded anything that is PUP or anything worse.

Image: [image: Error message]

Here are the proxies I've been using:

ip: 67.55.210.215
port: 80
type: http/https

ip: 173.255.118.111
port: 3128
type: http/https

Comment: Can't link image since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: As is, the image is useless. Please click the “More” button and make a screenshot of that or just copy the error code, the rest is useless anyway.

Comment: @DanielB Oh yeah, lol. Duh, Um I'll get that up. Thanks for the edit. BTW once I re-edit the post, can you help post the second image up as well? ;)

Comment: @DanielB nvm about that pic. it works if i edit. any answers?